# how timestamp format is picked

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a an SQL query on an Oracle database as:

```
select cast(systimestamp as timestamp) from dual.
```

It prints

```
"2016-02-26T10:36:57-08:00"
```

The question is, from where it is finding the format to cast?

Comment: It will be the NLS settings

Comment: how do i verify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NLS documentation is here : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1007035

You can check your NLS settings in v$paramter

```
select * from v$parameter where name like '%nls%'
```

You can pull the individual parameter :

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'
```

Comment: DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM this i get.  Is it same data?

Comment: Are you using sql developer to query the db? that has its own preferences - the question does not specify / make it clear. You are not casting it to a char, but it remains a timestamp, so sql developer preferences determine the format in its window. If it went to char, you should see the server format.

Comment: Preferences - Database - NLS